# How to create a postgresql based function to perform comparison on basis of a variable at each row and return different results for each case

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains various product categories. Under these categories there might be different products that are either being manufactured or outsourced from somewhere else. I need to determine the count of products that are being manufactured and outsourced for each category. If for a category there are no outsourced products then simply the count of manufactured products is to be returned else the details of the products need to be returned. Assume the details of the products to be name, cost price and selling price.

I am extremely sorry it my question is not clear. Please comment if any further explanation is required.

The table definition:

```
CATEGORY_ID              VARCHAR(400)
CATEGORY_NAME            VARCHAR(400)
PRODUCT_ID               VARCHAR(400)
PRODUCT_NAME             VARCHAR(400)
PRODUCT_TYPE             VARCHAR(400) ['MANUFACTURED' or 'OUTSOURCED']
CP                       INT
SP                       INT
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are trying to achieve. You should **[edit]** your question and add the code you have and explain what the root problem is, you are trying to solve. Chances are that you neither need PL/pgSQL nor `IF`

Comment: Please review [ask]. You are telling us a proposed solution WITHOUT indicating the problem. You do not know how to do the solution, fair enough, but neither can we without knowing the problem.

Comment: Please share the table definitions and the query you tried (even if it is not yet working)

Comment: "*else the details of the products need to be returned*" - I don't understand how that goes along with "*the count of products*". Those two parts seem to contradict each other. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

> *I need to determine the count of products that are being manufactured and outsourced for each category*

Sounds like you are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select category_name,
       count(*) filter (where product_type = 'MANUFACTURED') as num_manufactured,           
       count(*) filter (where product_type = 'OUTSOURCED') as num_outsourced
from the_table
group by category_name;
```